# Smooth code, but SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios, sigabrt

The crash log of SIGABRT from the device is pointing on the lines:

```
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request &error];
  if ([results count] > 0 ) { // SIGABRT on this line.
```

and (for the same device):

```
if (myfunc(myobj)) { // SIGABRT on this line.
```

where myobj is a pointer that must be nil from the app configuration, and it is initialized in the line just before the  line of the crash.
myfunc is a function looking like:

```
BOOL myfunc(id object) {
  return object != nil;
}
```

so i would consider the second crash as

```
myobj = something
if (myobj != nil) { // SIGABRT on this line.
```

My knowledge is not enough to understand the possibility of such crashes (probably they're even random) on certain devices (on the most devices everything works fine and stable).

Anyone had such issues or have an experience debugging it ?

Comment: Crashes are never 'random' if you do everything right.  There is usually some bold text accompanying SIGABRT exceptions.  That would be the most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way how a pointer comparison can crash. Also, if `myfunc` is not a function pointer, `if (myfunc(myobj))` cannot crash.

The Objective-C code has not problems either.

Are you sure you're interpreting the debugger's output correctly? Are the debugging symbols correct? Try turn off optimization.

Maybe you are looking at the wrong stack: Check all thread's stacks.

SIGABRT is a signal sent to tell the process that something's wrong. Maybe it's just iOS killing your app because memory is running out. Or the process hits `abort()` due to a failed assertion.

Comment: There is one way causing to crash when you touch pointer - when you just released the object and didn't set pointer to nil.

Comment: @SVGreg An app *might* crash if you **dereference** a dangling pointer. That does not happen in the posted code, except in `[results count]` which seems not to dangle.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for taking your time, that was kinda stupid of me not to check uuid of the report before asking. Thanks for your time, i'm completely agree with your statement, Nikolai, so that must be accepted. The report uuid is not the same as the app it was symbolicated against, the pointed code should work (i'm not crazy, hurray !)

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe, you might be interested that only a half of the logs were of a wrong version, it means at least "if (myobj != nil) {" must be really crashing :) Two interesting moments are that the app is running fine on thousands of other devices and that the reports show the app started several times against armv6, but mostly against armv7 mode on the crashing iphone3,1 (aka iPhone 4) with different bundle-ids, most probably the device was the same for both architectures (as reports were received by email) and i see it as an unnatural behavior.